Не могу сделать ссылку в таких скобках ``
Я не могу сделать ссылку в таких скобках `` Хотя у бота JeggyBot получилось. Все перерыл и ничего не нашел. Нуждаюсь в вашей помощи заранее спасибо!
Вот код:
@bot.command(aliases=["Инвайты"])
async def инвайты(ctx):
    invites = await ctx.guild.invites()
    if not invites:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description="❌ На этом сервере нет активных приглашений.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    invite_info = ""
    for idx, invite in enumerate(invites, start=1):
        invite_url = f"https://discord.gg/{invite.code}"
        invite_info += f"{idx}. [{invite.code}]({invite_url}) ---> **{invite.inviter}** [{invite.uses}]\n"

    embed = disnake.Embed(title="Список приглашений", description=invite_info, color=0x2b2d31)
    if ctx.guild.icon:
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

Вот как у меня бот реагирует на сообщения:

А вот как должно быть:


Так в вашем коде и нет этих кавычек. Чтобы понять что не так, нужно смотреть как вы пробовали сделать.

Попробуйте добавить `` вокруг {invite.code}.
Код получится таким:
@bot.command(aliases=["Инвайты"])
async def инвайты(ctx):
    invites = await ctx.guild.invites()
    if not invites:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description="❌ На этом сервере нет активных приглашений.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    invite_info = ""
    for idx, invite in enumerate(invites, start=1):
        invite_url = f"https://discord.gg/{invite.code}"
        invite_info += f"{idx}. [`{invite.code}`]({invite_url}) ---> **{invite.inviter}** [{invite.uses}]\n"

    embed = disnake.Embed(title="Список приглашений", description=invite_info, color=0x2b2d31)
    if ctx.guild.icon:
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


Вы гений! Реально большое спасибо!
